# What is the difference between onOpen(e) and onOpen()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have gone through many documentation from Google Apps Script and I have seen `onOpen(e)` and `onOpen()` are used in many examples. Both of them look familiar to me and I'm new to Google addon, which one is best to use for regular practice?

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*`onOpen(e)` with an event object brings contextual information that can be used in the function. If none of this information is needed, then you can omit the event object by using `onOpen()`. Both will run when the file to which the script is bound is opened, but you can only have one function with this name in your script.*

#### The Event Object:

Depending on the type of file that the script is bound to, the event object will have different parameters that can be accessed, as can be seen [in the event object documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

#### Example:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  e.source.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue("I ran!")
}
```

In this example, as a part of the event object passed to the script, the `source` parameter is a Spreadsheet object which you can use to manpulate the Spreadsheet to which the script is bound. Without the event object, you would have to directly call the `SpreadsheetApp` method to obtain the data:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue("I ran!")
}
```

This is a simple example showing the `source` parameter, but there are others such as `e.authMode` which can be used to determine the installation state of an add-on, and `e.user` which displays the email address of the user that ran the script.

You can read more information about the event object and how to use them for each trigger and service at the above link.

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)